# How the lock file is shared among the various mongods

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am trying to setup a shard and replica set.

My assumption procedure be like this :

1. Start a replica set (let it be only one, just for testing)
2. `mongo` then initiate replica
3. Start a config server (again let it be one, just for testing)
4. Start a shard server (again let that be just one)
5. Add the shard and enable `sharding` via `mongo`

What i did :

1. `mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath data/rs0-0 --unixSocketPrefix data/rs0-0`
2. `mongo` then `rs.initiate()`
3. `mongod --configsvr --dbpath data/rs0-0 --unixSocketPrefix data/rs0-0`

-- now stucked at step 3.

Error i find is 
`2017-05-22T20:00:13.857+0530 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: data/rs0-0/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

What i have tried :

i have tried with different directories for --unixSocketPrefix options, but each time it hits `data/rs0-0/mongod.lock` the same file. So it did not worked

It seems simple issue but unable to figure out how the lock file is shared among the various mongods (whether it be config server, or replica set, or shard server)

I am on mongodb `2.6.12`

Comment: why are you passing --unixSocketPrefix? Is it purposefully set?

Comment: actually i am running mongodb in isolated binaries directory in somewhere within home directory so it does not requires `sudo`. Hence i need to specify different lock file prefix

Comment: ok..that should be fine..You need to start mongod and config server with dbpath options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start `mongod` and `config server` with *different* dbpath options.
You can follow the following steps:

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath data/rs0-0 --unixSocketPrefix data/rs0-0
```

or

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath data/rs0-0
```

`mongo` then `rs.initiate()`

`mkdir -p /data/configdb`  (grant required permission recursively)

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/configdb --port 27019
```

Comment: this does solve the issue and answer is logical, config server also need a separate database